Can't access Web Viewer for Hanwha DVR on browser
I try to access Web Viewer for Hanwha DVR on Web.
Because company use CCTV web camera(Camera type HRD-442).
It's 32bit system so I need to use Internet Explorer mode.
1.access IP from company intra NW.
2.Login with admin ID/PS.
3.WISENET is open but no video shown.
4.Installer pop up below on the browser and clic it and execute YES of installer(Unknown program) with PC admin.
5.Wizard ("WebViewer DVR 1.0.1.1 Setup") says "All internet Explorers will be closed. Do you want to proceed?"
I selected "No" → Brower changes a bit white.Once I close browser, Installer Wizard pop up.
Clic "install" and "finish". At this time,wizard says "WebViewer DVR 1.0.1.1 has been installed on your computer."
But after that, I open browser and access the same IP, nothing has changed.
I changed internet option of IE but It repeats the same thing..
Browser reload button is always moving or ”ｘ”．
What else am I missing?
Chaned ActiveX on Internet option of Internet Explorer.
Added this IP to reliable site on Internet Option.
